# APEX Calendar - putting an ID on for a range of dates and not just one date only

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar

I have a table called Bed_registry (for a hospital database)

```
CREATE TABLE Bed_Registry (
 Visit_ID       CHAR(5) ,
 Bed_ID     CHAR(5) ,
 Admission_Date DATE        NOT NULL,
 Discharge_Date DATE,
 CONSTRAINT BR_PK PRIMARY KEY(Visit_ID, Bed_ID),
 CONSTRAINT BR_FK_visit
   FOREIGN KEY (Visit_ID)
   REFERENCES Visit (Visit_ID)
   ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT BR_FK_bed
   FOREIGN KEY (Bed_ID)
   REFERENCES Bed (Bed_ID)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I created a SQL calendar for this table and I could put the `Bed_ID` onto the calendar on only one of either `Admission_Date` or `Discharge_Date`. I was wondering if there was any way to display `Bed_id` on not just one of those dates but on all the days in between `Admission_Date` and `Discharge_Date`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what's a "SQL calendar"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified. It's a calendar made on a region on a page in ORACLE APEX application express

Comment: You should always include desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a query that generates dates between Admission_date and Discharge_date. Then you can create a calendar based on this query.

To achieve this, you need first a table with the numbers 0...n, where n is large enough to cover the maximum number of stay-days in a hospital.

Table Days:

```
Day
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

Then your query will look like:

```
select Admission_date, Discharge_date, 
       Admission_date + days.day AS Occupied_date
from   beds, 
       (select days.day from days order by days.day) days
where  Admission_date + days.day <= Discharge_date
order by Admission_date, Occupied_date;
```

See [sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b738a/1)

Comment: +1 You can do this without a "days" table, by generating the rows on the flow, e.g. using `SELECT ROWNUM AS day FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: thanks for your feedback, I'm not familiar with Oracle. I wouldn't recommend a DBMS specific solution, anyway, although I think the SQL standard should have a way to generate relations from implicit sets defined by functions.

Comment: No problem. The OP is talking about Apex, though, which means they're not going to be worrying about cross-platform portability.

Comment: Sure, and that's usually the problem. There is always a reason to deviate from the standard. Been there, done that :)